# Is my probability formula correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

### The Question

> The response rate to telephone polls is around $2{\%}$. Of people who
> respond to telephone polls, currently about $40{\%}$ approve of the
> President. Suppose we perform a telephone poll by calling a random
> sample of $50,000$ registered voters.
>
> (a) Let $X$ be a binomial random variable representing the number of
> people who respond to the telephone poll. What is the expected value
> and standard deviation of $X$?
>
> (b) Let $Y$ be a binomial random variable representing the number of
> people who respond to the telephone poll and approve of the President.
> What are the expected value and standard deviation of $Y$?
>
> (c) Use R to find the probability that at least $420$ people respond
> to the telephone poll and approve of the President. Give your R code.

### My Understanding

This is my thought process:

For 1a, $X \sim \mathscr{B}(N, P)$, $N$ being the $50,000$ registered voters and $P$ being the $2\%$ (rate at which people are answering polls), so it would be $EV = 50000 * .02=1000$. The variance is $N * P *(1-P)$ so plugging in the numbers I would get $980$ and to get standard deviation it would just be the square-root of that so $31.3$

For 1b, it would be similar except replace $P$ with $40\% (.4)$, so the expected value would be $20,000$. The variance would be $50,000 * .4 * .6 = 12000$. Taking the square root would be $109.54$

Using R to find probability of at least $420$ people would just be `dbinom(420, 50000, .02)`

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe this is correct. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format any mathematical expressions, it's easier to read and makes it clearer what your intentions are.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I fixed it.

Comment: Looks much better, thanks! 1a looks good. For 1b, it's the number of people who respond and approve, so the proportion should be $p = 0.02*0.40 = 0.008$.

Comment: Could you make the text of the problem statement $\tiny \text{smaller}?$  Can still read it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to 1a looks correct.

For 1b, you're right that its similar, but the proportion is not $40\%$. We're given that $Y$ represents the number of people who respond to the telephone poll and approve of the president. The probability that somebody responds and approves is

$$ P[\text{Respond} \cap \text{Approve}] = P[\text{Approve} | \text{Respond}]*P[\text{Respond}] $$
$$ = 0.40*0.02 $$
$$ = 0.008 . $$

So, we have $Y \sim \mathscr{B}(50000, 0.008)$. Then, the expected value is

$$ E[Y] = np = 50000*0.008 = 400 .$$

The variance is

$$ V[Y] = np(1-p) = 50000*.008*.992 = 396.8 , $$

which gives us a standard deviation of

$$ SD[Y] = \sqrt{V[Y]} = \sqrt{396.8} \approx 19.92 $$

For 1c, you don't want to use `dbinom`, it gives you the probability of a specific value of $Y$. If you used `dbinom(420, 50000, .008)`, you'd end up calculating $P[Y = 420]$, but in this case, we want $P[Y \ge 420]$.

The more appropriate function in this case is `pbinom` ([R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.3/topics/Binomial)). Using that function, `pbinom(k,n,p)` results in the cumulative distribution up to and including the value of $k$. So, `pbinom(k,50000,0.008)` would be equal to $P[Y \le k]$. Then, since

$$ P[Y \ge 420] = 1 - P[Y < 420] = 1 - P[Y \le 419], $$

we have $k = 419$, and can calculate it with `1-pbinom(419,50000,0.008)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer Key**

(a) $X\sim \mathscr B (50000,.02)$ so that $E(X)=50000(.02)=1000$, $\sigma_X=\sqrt{50000(.02)(.98)}=31.30495$. Yup yours looks right.

(b) You want $Y\sim\mathscr B(50000, .02*.4)=\mathscr B(50000,.008)$. It says that of the people who respond, 40% are in favor. So not 40% of the whole population is in favor. This is a conditional probability, but you don't really need to know the term to be able to multiply the two numbers. Repeating the calculation in (a), you get $E(Y)=50000(.008)=400$ and $\sigma_Y=\sqrt{50000*.008*.992}=19.91984$

(c) The correct commands are either of the following. Subtracting the lower tail from 1 is the same as getting the upper tail. You don't want to use dbinom, because if you do, you will have to type it hundreds of times, e.g. 1-[dbinom(0,50000,.008)+dbinom(1,50000,.008)+...+dbinom(419,50000,.008)].

```
> pbinom(419,50000,.008,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.1637013
> 1-pbinom(419,50000,.008,lower.tail=TRUE)
[1] 0.1637013
```